# Javascript: unset interval from within the interval's function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, intervals

I'm using setInterval to update a users statistics with a group of people on the site. If it 403s, that means the group kicked the guy out, and I don't see it reasonable to just continuously send requests since to get back in to said group, the user would have to agree to something on their profile page. So, Say I have:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/retreivestats',
    success: function(data) {
      //update the page with the new stats
    },
    error: function(errorObj) {
      if (errorObj.status == 403) {
        //someone took away the users perms to retrieve stats, unset the interval
      }
    }
  });
}, 30000);
```

How would use actually unset this interval from within the error function?

Comment: You can use clearinterval http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a variable and assign `setInterval` to it and use `clearInterval`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
   $.ajax({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/api/retreivestats',
     success: function(data) {
       //update the page with the new stats
     },
     error: function(errorObj) {
       if (errorObj.status == 403) {
         //someone took away the users perms to retrieve stats, unset the interval
        clearInterval(interval);
       }
     }
   });
}, 30000);
```

> **interval** is the identifier of the repeated action you want to cancel.
>   This ID is returned from setInterval().

Answer (score 2):

You just store a reference to the interval, and use `clearInterval`

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/retreivestats',
    success: function(data) {
      //update the page with the new stats
    },
    error: function(errorObj) {
      if (errorObj.status == 403) {
          clearInterval(myInterval);
      }
    }
  });
}, 30000);
```